# not getting a desired output in armstrong number

Tags: c

its a program to find armstrong number between desired range 
suppose i want to find amstrong between range 100 to 1000
then it is showing output as 370 371 407 but not 153 can't find what is going wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
int num,start,end,n,rem,res;
printf("Enter the range :");
scanf("%d %d",&start,&end);
printf("Amstrong number between %d and %d are : ",start,end);
for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
{
    //int i=153;
    num=i;
    n=0;
    while(num)
    {
        num/=10;
        ++n;
    }
    num=i;
    res=0;
    while(num)
    {
        rem=num%10;
        res=res+pow(rem,n);
        num/=10;
    }
    if(res==i)
        printf("%d\t",i);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: NoRep: https://onlinegdb.com/rkv818kXS

Comment: i think something is wrong with `pow()` function . I wrote another `power()` function in code and it is running fine so what is wrong happening with `pow()` function

Comment: `pow` function takes `double`s and returns a `double`. You probably get a rounding error and the `if (res==i)` doesn't get true.

Comment: I ran the OPs code, under linux 18.04 and gcc.  The result was the correct 4 outputs.   I suspect your problem is using the `pow()` function

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code on Hackerrank Editor and it works perfectly fine and prints 153 as well.

Try it out. Also attaching the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: so i thinks its compiler problem as it is running fine on dev c++ but not on code:blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main() {
  int number, i, digit, sum, start, end;
  printf("Enter the range :");
  scanf("%d %d", &start, &end);
  for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    number = i;
    sum = 0;

    while (number > 0) {
        digit = number % 10;
        sum += digit * digit * digit;
        number /= 10;
    }

    if (sum == i) {
        printf("%d\t", i);
    }
}
```

}

Try this one

Comment: He needs an integer power function.  Harding coding the multiplies to a power of 3 will break the rest of his app.

Answer (score 0):

User KamilCuk seems to have had the right idea.

Pardon the usage of c++ instead of c, however, the reason for your unexpected output (or lack thereof, in this case) is fundamentally the same.

I've tested it for the specific value of 407 instead of 153, because that's the armstrong number that wasn't working properly for me (though this may vary).

```
    void checkArm()
        {
            cout << "Armstrong numbers in range are:" << endl;
            for (int i = 407; i <= 407; i++)
            { //isolate digits
                int digHun, digTen, digOne;
                digHun = i / 100;
                digTen = i / 10 - 10 * digHun;
                digOne = i % 10;
                cout << "Test 1: " << i << endl;
    
        // the pow function itself provides expected output on terminal
                cout << pow(digHun, 3) << endl;
                cout << pow(digTen, 3) << endl;
                cout << pow(digOne, 3) << endl;
                
    //here's the problem!
    
                cout << "bool check supplied: " << ((pow(digHun, 3) + pow(digTen, 3) + pow(digOne, 3)) == i) << endl;
                cout << "bool check 407: " << ((pow(digHun, 3) + pow(digTen, 3) + pow(digOne, 3)) == 407) << endl;
                cout << "bool check typecasted: " << (int(pow(digHun, 3) + pow(digTen, 3) + pow(digOne, 3)) == i) << endl;
        
//part that was supposed to print 407 if it weren't for problem described above
                if ((pow(digHun, 3) + pow(digTen, 3) + pow(digOne, 3)) == i)
                {
                    cout << "Main test" << i << endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

The output for my compiler is:

```
bool check supplied: 0
bool check 407: 0
bool check typecasted: 1
```

**Notice how the condition holds true only when our expression is typecast to type int before comparison.** Just convert this expression to type int to get your job done.

**In essence, for both of these programs, the issue is associated with the pow function. Though there are differences between c and cpp, pow() returns a double value for both.** Moreover, arguments passed to pow() are implicitly typecasted to double before executing.

(Taking an example, your compiler is converting 153 to 153.00000etc and then comparing it with 153.00023etc, which it the output of the pow() functions. These don't turn out to be equal in the case of double comparison. Actually, you could verify this by using the setprecision() function. This will yield what the compiler is seeing during comparison)

You can verify that pow(), indeed, returns a double value [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/).

I hope that this clarifies the issue from a conceptual standpoint (even if the language is different).